# Combinatorics- Marble Placement Order

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

You have 20 marbles each of colors blue, red, yellow, and green (80 total marbles). The marbles of each color are identical. In how many ways can you put all of the marbles in a row?

I think the answer is $80!/(4*20!)$ but I can't be sure. If it's not them I'm lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhh... I think you should be looking for   $$\frac{80!}{(20!)^4}$$ ( due to repetition in colours)